# Loading multiple versions of an object with XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I've been given a project in which I am to design a "universal" way to store store values and modify them as needed (outside of the running program). The values are used for testing purposes (i.e. max and min voltage and current thresholds). Ideally I should be able to share these values across multiple programs and projects as well.

In the past, we would define our own scripting files for this purpose (usually some form of a CSV file) and, needless to say, it was messy and inefficient.

Now, my immediate thought when given this project was to use object serialization (XML serialization in particular because it's human-readable). Our tests are so varied that there's really no way to come up with a "universal" format; so the next best thing to do is automate the formatting. It allows me to deserialize an object upon program entry and subsequently serialize it again when I'm done with it. Most importantly, I can go into the generated XML file and modify its contents by hand. Plus, I can use the data like a regular object. So I went about storing all these values in objects and serializing them.

However, our test parameters change frequently; sometimes we may add or remove test cases and whatnot. Unfortunately, in order to do this I need to modify my objects. Now I'm left with different versions of the same object and I need to support all of them (or at least up-convert the data to the latest version of the object type).

Of course one solution would be to use inheritance for each version, but that gets messy and it's not really a natural way to code (especially when you're testing hardware). Reflection could be another option, but I presume that'd involve a manual parser (and I still need to support multiple versions). I'd appreciate any input on the best approach to take here. Thanks

Note that I've used `DataContractSerializer` to handle my serialization and deserialization.

---

Here's an example class of how my code works; the :

**Main function:**

```
namespace Test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerializableSingleton<Class1>.initInstance("class1Singleton.xml");
            Class1 obj1 = SerializableSingleton<Class1>.Instance;

            Class1 obj2 = new SerializableInstance<Class1>("class1Instance.xml").Data;
        }
    }
}
```

**Class to be serialized:**

```
namespace Test
{
    [DataContract()]
    class Class1 : AbstractSerializeableObject
    {
        protected override XMLVersion ObjectVersion
        {
            get { return version; }
        }

        XMLVersion version = new XMLVersion(1, 0, 0, "Init Version");


        [DataMember(Name = "First Number")]
        int number = 1;

        [DataMember()]
        string str = "hello";

        [DataMember(Name = "Nested Class")]
        NestedClass1 nClass = new NestedClass1();

        [DataContract()]
        class NestedClass1 :AbstractSerializeableObject
        {
            protected override XMLVersion ObjectVersion
            {
                get { return version; }
            }

            XMLVersion version = new XMLVersion(1, 0, 0, "Init Version");

            [DataMember(Name = "Second Number")]
            int number = 2;

            [DataMember()]
            string str = "world";
        }

    }
}
```

**Resulting XML Files:**

*class1Singleton.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Class1 xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Test">
    <First_x0020_Number>1</First_x0020_Number>
    <Nested_x0020_Class>
        <Second_x0020_Number>2</Second_x0020_Number>
        <str>world</str>
    </Nested_x0020_Class>
    <str>hello</str>
</Class1>
```

*class1Instance.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Class1 xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Test">
    <First_x0020_Number>1</First_x0020_Number>
    <Nested_x0020_Class>
        <Second_x0020_Number>2</Second_x0020_Number>
        <str>world</str>
    </Nested_x0020_Class>
    <str>hello</str>
</Class1>
```

Note that everything here appears as it should; there are no issues with the XML files generated (thus far). These are the results I would expect. There are many layers to the singleton and instance stuff and that isn't really what's important. The important thing is the serialization itself. The important part is the serialization itself and versioning.

**Here's how I do the serialization and deserialization:**

```
namespace XMLSerializationLib
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The XmlSerializer is used solely to encapulate the serialization and
    /// deserialization of objects. It uses generics so most objects can make use
    /// of this library, provided that they heed to the warning(s) below:
    ///
    /// -- The object to be serialized MUST have a default, non-parameterized
    ///    contructor
    ///
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> The object type to be serialized/deserialized </typeparam>
    internal static class XmlSerializer<T>
    {
        /* ========================================================================= */
        /* Functions                                                                 */
        /* ========================================================================= */

        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes an object of type T into an XML file
        /// which can be edited outside of the program.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj"> The object which should be serialized </param>
        /// <param name="path"> The path of the XML file to be generated </param>
        internal static void Serialize(T obj, string path)
        {
            if (!(obj is AbstractSerializeableObject))
                throw new SerializerTypeException("Serialized Object must inherit AbstractSerializeableObject");

            // Make XML readable
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.IndentChars = "\t";


#if _NET_4_5_
            // Enable serialization of `readonly` properties and types
            System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializeReadOnlyTypes = true;
#endif

            // Write to XML
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(path, settings))
            {
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                serializer.WriteObject(writer, obj);
                writer.Close();
            } 
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes a provided XML file and stores the retrieved data inside
        /// an object of type T.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path"> The path of the XML file to be loaded </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// An filled object of type T; if the provided XML cannot be
        /// deserialized, then it returns a T object with its default
        /// properties.
        /// </returns>
        internal static T Deserialize(string path)
        {
            T obj;

            DataContractSerializer deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(path);

#if _NET_4_5_
            // Enable deserialization of `readonly` properties and types
            System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializeReadOnlyTypes = true;
#endif

            if (deserializer.IsStartObject(reader))
                obj = (T)deserializer.ReadObject(reader);
            else
                obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

            reader.Close();

            if (!(obj is AbstractSerializeableObject))
                throw new SerializerTypeException("Serialized Object must inherit AbstractSerializeableObject");

            return obj;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Exception to be thrown if the provided object T does not inherit
        /// AbstractSerializeableObject.
        /// </summary>
        internal class SerializerTypeException : Exception
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Exception constructor
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="message"> Error message </param>
            public SerializerTypeException(string message)
                : base(message)
            {
            }
        }


 }
}
```

Now the issue is as follows: Suppose I were to take my `Class1` object and modify the `number` field to equal `382000` for instance. Then I were to remove the `str` field entirely and add a new field called `dbl` which takes the value of `pi`. The resulting class would look like this:

**Modified Class1**

```
namespace Test
{
    [DataContract()]
    class Class1 : AbstractSerializeableObject
    {
        protected override XMLVersion ObjectVersion
        {
            get { return version; }
        }

        XMLVersion version = new XMLVersion(1, 0, 0, "Init Version");


        [DataMember(Name = "First Number")]
        int number = 382000;

        [DataMember()]
        double dbl = 3.14;

        [DataMember(Name = "Nested Class")]
        NestedClass1 nClass = new NestedClass1();

        [DataContract()]
        class NestedClass1 :AbstractSerializeableObject
        {
            protected override XMLVersion ObjectVersion
            {
                get { return version; }
            }

            XMLVersion version = new XMLVersion(1, 0, 0, "Init Version");

            [DataMember(Name = "Second Number")]
            int number = 2;

            [DataMember()]
            string str = "world";
        }

    }
}
```

Now suppose I'm running an old version of my program with the original version of `Class1` on one machine (**Machine 1**) and updated version with the new `Class1` on another machine (**Machine 3**). And for argument's sake, let's say I have some intermediate version of `Class1` running on a third machine (**Machine2**). Now I would like to be able to take the XML file generated by **Machine 1** and fast-forward it so that the compatible data will be able to work on **Machine 2** and **Machine 3**; all new data-fields will of course take on some default value.

Answer (score 0):

In similar situation I use console application to update old xml's to new structure.
For this I wrote my realization of IDataContractSurrogate:

```
public class SerializerTypeSurrogate : IDataContractSurrogate
        {
            public virtual Type GetDataContractType(Type type)
            {
                return type == typeof(Charge) ? typeof(OldCharge) : type;
            }

            public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
            {
                return obj;
            }

            public virtual object GetDeserializedObject(Object obj, Type targetType)
            {
                var oldClass1= obj as OldClass1;
                        return oldClass1 != null ? new Class1(oldClass1) : obj;
        }

            public Type GetReferencedTypeOnImport(string typeName,
                string typeNamespace, object customData)
            {
                return null;
            }

            public System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration ProcessImportedType(
                System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration,
                System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit compileUnit)
            {
                return typeDeclaration;
            }



            public object GetCustomDataToExport(Type clrType, Type dataContractType)
            {
                return null;
            }

            public object GetCustomDataToExport(System.Reflection.MemberInfo memberInfo, Type dataContractType)
            {
                return null;
            }

            public void GetKnownCustomDataTypes(Collection<Type> customDataTypes)
            {
            }
        }
```

You should temporarily keep old and new classes and new class should have constructor from old class object, but you can remove this after transformation of all old xmls in new form.

To transform from old to new form you should use next code:

```
    var oldentity = Deserialize<T>(oldXml,
        new SerializerTypeSurrogate());
    var newXml = FormalizedChangeRecord.Serialize<T>(card);

public static TCard Deserialize<T>(string xmlData, IDataContractSurrogate surrogate)            {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (T), new Type[0], 10000, true, true, surrogate);
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(changeRecord.CardData))
        {
            using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, new XmlReaderSettings { CloseInput = false }))
            {
                var entity= (TCard)serializer.ReadObject(xmlReader);
                return entity;
            }
        }
    }
public static string Serialize<T>(T entity)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (T));
            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (
                    var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter,
                        new XmlWriterSettings
                {
                            CloseOutput = false,
                            Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false),
                            OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
                            Indent = true
                        }))
                {
                    serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, entity);
                }
                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: hmm... would I have to keep old classes around until I've gathered all versions of the old file? I'm also looking into using WCF because, as far as I can tell, it allows me to modify a class without having to create a new one and retain the old one. At this point in time the classes that I'll be serializing only contain data and accessors, so persistent services shouldn't be needed.

Comment: DataContractSerializer serialize properties as sequence, so if you add new properties to class you should add properties to end of sequence with [DataMember(Order=)] attribute. In this case deserialization will work out of the box.

Comment: hmm, and then what about removing or modifying fields?

Comment: Removed fields will not leverage on deserialized data of new class. Modification won't work.